# Convergence tests for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have this infinite sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

anyone knows if this series is converging and if so how do I prove it?

Comment: What does $n**2$ mean?

Comment: I think $n^2$ (** is ^ in python).

Comment: Do the terms converge to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A big hint:** for a series $\sum_n a_n$ to converge, a [necessary (not sufficient, but necessary) condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand) is that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =0$.

*However*, here, since $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = \sin'(0)=\cos 0=1$...

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused, are you sure that the this condition is happening here, because i thought this sum is diverging

Comment: @איתישולמן It is diverging: the *necessary* condition for convergence that $a_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ is **not** satisfied, so the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Check the necessary condition of cenvergence. What about $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)?$$